# An intuitive property of Brownian motion

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, conditional-expectation, levy-processes

Let $B$ be a Brownian motion (in fact, I have in mind a Levy process). 
Let $I_s := [a_s,b_s]$ be an interval for all $s \in [0,2t]$.

How do you prove the following statement rigorously, just using the stationary and independent increments of $B$?

$$P(B_s \in I_s \forall s \in [0,2t]) \leq 
P(B_s \in I_s \forall s \in [0,t]) \cdot \sup_{x \in I_t} P(x + B_s \in I_{s+t} \forall s \in [0,t]). $$

It's clear 'by drawing a picture' and using intuitive understanding of independent stationary increments. But I'd like to see a very formal proof if possible.

Comment: What does $x\in B_t$ mean?

Comment: Woooops thanks! I meant $I_t$ (now edited appropriately).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\{\mathcal F_s\}$ be the filtration associated with Brownian motion. Condition on $\mathcal F_t$, and use the Markov property and tower property of conditional expectation:
\begin{align*}
P(B_s\in I_s\text{ for all }s\in[0,2t]) &= E\Big[\mathbf1_{\{B_s\in I_s\text{ for }s\in[0,t]\}}P\big(B_s\in I_s\text{ for }s\in(t,2t]\,\big|\,\mathcal F_t\big)\Big]\\
&=E\Big[\mathbf1_{\{B_s\in I_s\text{ for }s\in[0,t]\}}P\big(B_t+(B_s-B_t)\in I_s\text{ for }s\in(t,2t]\,\big|\,B_t\big)\Big]\\
&\le E\Big[\mathbf1_{\{B_s\in I_s\text{ for }s\in[0,t]\}}\sup_{x\in I_t}P\big(x+(B_s-B_t)\in I_s\text{ for }s\in(t,2t]\,\big|\,B_t\big)\Big]\\
&=E\Big[\mathbf1_{\{B_s\in I_s\text{ for }s\in[0,t]\}}\sup_{x\in I_t}P\big(x+B_u\in I_{t+u}\text{ for }u\in(0,t]\big)\Big]\\
&=P(B_s\in I_s\text{ for }s\in[0,t])\sup_{x\in I_t}P(x+B_s\in I_{s+t}\text{ for }s\in[0,t]).
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks! I wrote that down too --- My problem is justifying the inequality formally. The conditional probability before the inequality is (formally) a random variable, and what I want to know is how to justify deterministically bounding it by the supremum  by using the definition of conditional probability. Does that make sense?

Comment: More generally, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent and $g$ is non-negative, one has $\mathbf1_{\{X\in A\}} E[g(X, Y) \, | \, X]\le\sup_{x\in A} E[g(x, Y)]$. This is an elementary application of the definition of conditional expectation which I encourage you to try yourself.

Comment: Ok cheers Jason, will do. Appreciate it.

Comment: PS would be great if you could have a look at my other Brownian motion question...
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2541610/conditional-expectation-of-a-brownian-motion